# Сбились настройки на android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, импорт

Здраствуйте,у меня такая проблема что я не могу использовать ArrayAdapter,Spinner,я их подключил в Android Studio.
Эта проблема появилась после обновления 3.5.3
После чего,пытался настроить JDK,нажимая на лампочку слева.Выбрал вроде как JDK 13.

```
 package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int quantity=0;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList spinnerArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    HashMap goodsMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinnerArrayList=new ArrayList();

        spinnerArrayList.add("guitar");
        spinnerArrayList.add("drums");
        spinnerArrayList.add("keyboard");

        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerArrayList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        goodsMap=new HashMap();
        goodsMap.put("guitar",500);
        goodsMap.put("drums",1500);
        goodsMap.put("keyboard",1000);
    }

    public void increaseQuantity(View view) {
        quantity++;
        TextView sumIncrease=findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        sumIncrease.setText(""+quantity);
    }

    public void decreaseQuantity(View view) {
        quantity--;
        if(quantity<=0) quantity=0;
        TextView sumDeacrease=findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        sumDeacrease.setText(""+quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит "не могу использовать"?

Comment: Для нормальной работы студии лучше использовать вариант 'Embedded JDK' (она располагается в папке самой студии). Если что-то сломалось после обновлений, можно попробовать сделать синхронизацию и ребилд. Если не помогло - почистить кеш (ищите в меню 'File'). Если ничего не помогает - опишите подробнее симптомы и что там пишет ваша лампочка.